# AWS Amplify graphQL API : Filter subscription by value in array

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I've seen that you can create custom subscription that are only triggered if the argument you are giving match the one in the model, for exemple:

```
type Post @model {
 id: ID!
 author: ID!
 editors: [ID]
}

type Subscription {
 onCreatePosteByAuthorId(authorId: ID!): Post @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createPost"])
}
```

But is there a way to filter subscriptions based on if the editors array contains a certain ID ?